# Is it safe to change the IP address and domain name of an Chef Node?

Tags: chef

I have a Chef Node that I'm initially setting up on one network that I need to (physically) move to another network.  When this happens, I want the IP address and domain name to change, and the Node name and simple hostname to stay the same.

I know I can do this by deleting the Chef Node and recreating it.  Could I also do it by editing Node attributes?   Or would that break the client keys or (worse still) the server?

(I'm using Chef 10.16.2 ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating the node (and client) with the new name is one option, but you can preserve the ones you already have.  This requires client configuration - by the time the node retrieves attributes from the Chef server, it's already decided what its name is.

By default, chef-client will set the node name to the fully-qualified domain name of the host, as returned by ohai.  You can check what name will be used by invoking ohai directly:

```
zts@chef ~ % ohai fqdn
[
  "chef.nat0.cryptocracy.com"
]
```

If that changes when you move the host, you'll need to edit `/etc/chef/client.rb` to set the desired nodename:

```
node_name "mynode.example.com"
```

Take a look at [Chef Docs - client.rb](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_client.html) for more about this configuration file.

Comment: Yup.  It just worked.  (I didn't need to tweak the node name.  I deliberately didn't use the fqdn as node name when I created it in the first place because I knew it would be changing.)